# How get access for read or write file in electron app for express server?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

In my app i am using

- express server
- electron

in express server i want read and write file in app.
Express server in `preload.js`

- electron main.js:

```
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      contextIsolation: false,
      sandbox: false,
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

- example express in preload.js

```
  fs.writeFileSync(`${__dirname}/words.json`, 
    JSON.stringify(student, null, 4), function(error) { })
```

When i write app and start local server app is working.

When i running app i get error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/lib/words/resources/app/words.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:466)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1366)
    at /usr/lib/words/resources/app/preload.js:65
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95)
    at next (/usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95)
    at /usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281
    at Function.process_params (/usr/lib/words/resources/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335)
```

How access permission in electron app ?